# Windsor Castle: A shorthand fluent interface for Resolve() parameters?

Tags: inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

Is there some kind of a shorthand fluent interface for creating a parameters dictionary to be provided to the IWindsorContainer.Resolve() method? Something like:

```
container.Resolve<ConsoleApp>(Parameters.Add("args", args).Add("banana", X).Add...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question: it looks like I forgot about collection initializers:

```
container.Resolve<ConsoleApp>(new Hashtable(){{"args", args}});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also pass an anonymous object as parameter:

```
container.Resolve<ConsoleApp>(new { args, banana = X });
```

Answer (score 1):

As of 2021, there is much safer and convenient API for this - the Arguments class.

You may use it like this:

```
var arguments = new Arguments
{
    { "args", args },
    { "banana", X },
    { typeof(IService), new MyService() }
};

container.Resolve<ConsoleApp>(arguments);
```

There's also Fluent API:

```
var arguments = new Arguments()
    .AddNamed("args", args)
    .AddTyped<IService>(new MyService());

container.Resolve<ConsoleApp>(arguments);
```

Here's the link: https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/arguments.md